# Find resolution of an image in dpi value uploaded using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip, dpi

In our Rails Application, we are uploading images using `Paperclip` gem. I would like to know if there is a way to find DPI value of such an uploaded image?